# How to create a switch statement from enum type so it automatically fills case for each enum member?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, enums, vscode-snippets

This feature exists in Visual Studio Professional, but no idea how to do it in VS Code.

For example I have `Colors` enum like this:

```
enum Colors {
    Red,
    Blue,
```

So when I write a switch statement like this:

```
function getColor(colors: Colors) {
 switch (colors) 
}
```

The editor to automatically fill every case for me, like:

```
switch (colors) {
    case Colors.Red:      
      break;
    case Colors.Blue:      
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is extension that covers this case called Hocus Pocus:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nicoespeon.hocus-pocus

When installed just hover over switch statement and open quick fix menu (ctrl + . or cmd + .) and You should see `Create all cases` option